# run cocos2d-js in internet explorer 8

Tags: webgl, cocos2d-js

Is there any way to have a cocos2d-js web game run on IE8 ?
I was looking for something like a plugin ( google had one , chrome frame , but has beed dismissed )
even excanvas.js does not work , and iewebgl plugin seems fully abandoned

Comment: Why do you want to run it with IE8 in first place?
Imo it wont be possible. Cocos is updated quite often and there are still lot of bugs in js version. So even if lets say excanvas.js would work and you would be able to run your game, there would be still a lot of problems requiring hard workarounds.

Comment: it should be used internally by a firma that installa ie8 in its employers' computers .

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say you can't.

[WebGL is only supported in IE11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl), and even [canvas requires IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas).

If excanvas doesn't do the trick, then I'm sorry, but you are better off using flash or some other technology that doesn't require HTML5 functionality (or get the company to update their browsers).

Comment: as well as excanvas , i have found another project , flashcanvas , that should simulate a canvas with flash . in both cases, cocos2 starts , and then i get an error "cannot delete 'window._p'" , i suppose a difference in javascript too

Comment: I don't really know what to say.. Are you already experienced in Cocos2d-JS or do you already have the game implemented? If not, maybe you should look into other technologies. Alternatively, you could compile the game as a win32 application? I know, it wouldn't be inside a browser anymore, but seriously, is it completely off limits for the players to use anything newer than IE8?

Comment: How can i compile the game as a win32 application ? this could be a solution, through an active-x control i may run it inside the browser.

Comment: Assuming you've got the cocos console working OK and Visual Studio 2012 or above installed (you can use the free community edition), just go to your folder destination in a command prompt and execute `cocos compile -p win32`.